# Why does importing a typescript component crashes the app in release mode but not in debugging?

Tags: typescript, react-native, bottom-sheet

I am importing a bottom sheet written in typescript into a class component and it does work correctly in debugging mode but unfortunately not in release mode. I tried checking the logcat, but it does not seem to print any readable error code or message.

I have wrapped the typescript component inside a try catch but it still crashes the app.
Here is the typescript component:

```
export default function App(data: any) {
   const ref = useRef<BottomSheetRefProps>(null);

   const onPressCloseBottomSheet = useCallback(() => {
      const isActive = ref?.current?.isActive();
      if (isActive) {
         ref?.current?.scrollTo(0);
         data.data.onCloseBottomSheetParam();
      } else {
         ref?.current?.scrollTo(-(styles.windowHeight / 1.8));
      }
   }, []);

   var custom_view = data.data.custom_view;

   try {
      return (
         <GestureHandlerRootView style={styles.bottomSheetOuterWrapper}>
            <BlurView
               style={styles.blurViewStyle}
               blurRadius={1}
               blurType={'dark'}
            />
            <View style={styles.innerContainerBottomSheet}>
               <BottomSheet ref={ref}>
                  {data.data.onCloseBottomSheetParam}
                  {custom_view}                 
               </BottomSheet>
            </View>
         </GestureHandlerRootView>
      );
   } catch (e) {
      alert('BottomSheet called failed!');
      return null;
   };
}
```

and here is the part of class component where I import and use the bottom sheet:

...

```
try {
 const customview = (<ScrollView
    contentContainerStyle={styles.userEmojisScrollableView}>
    {Object.keys(all_active_users).map(e =>
       all_active_users[e].act &&
       <View style={styles.userEmojisScrollableInnerView}>
          <View style={styles.usrEmojisNameImgWrapper}>
             <FastImage
                source={all_active_users[e].profile_pic ? {
                   uri: all_active_users[e].profile_pic,
                   priority: FastImage.priority.high,
                   cache: FastImage.cacheControl.immutable,
                } : require('../assets/user.png')}
                style={styles.usrEmojiPic}
                resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover}
             />
             <Text style={styles.usrEmojiUsernameTxt}>
                {all_active_users[e].name}
             </Text>
          </View>
       </View>
    )}
 </ScrollView>);

  return (<BottomSheet data={{ custom_view: customview, onCloseBottomSheetParam: (() => this.onCloseBottomSheet()) }} />);
  } catch (e) {
     logErrors('openModalActiveUsers()', e);
     alert('openModalActiveUsers() failed!');
     return;
  };
```

...

Can anyone suggest what might be wrong? Why does this work in debugging mode but not in release mode?

**UPDATE**
I have figured out that the app crashes only when there is a Scrollview passed to the typescript function. If I remove the Scrollview and pass the rest of React child components it does not fail/crash.
Now the question is why Scrollview is making the typescript crash my app?

Answer (score 0):

Alright I finally found out what's the problem. Apparently, Typescript requires that all nested child components inside a scrollview have a unique key. So after adding them it does not fail anymore.

```
    {Object.keys(all_active_users).map(e =>
         all_active_users[e].act &&
         <View key={'outer_view_' + e} style={styles.userEmojisScrollableInnerView}>
            <View key={'inner_view_' + e} style={styles.usrEmojisNameImgWrapper}>
               <FastImage
                  key={'image_' + e}
                  source={all_active_users[e].profile_pic ? {
                     uri: all_active_users[e].profile_pic,
                     priority: FastImage.priority.high,
                     cache: FastImage.cacheControl.immutable,
                  } : require('../assets/user.png')}
                  style={styles.usrEmojiPic}
                  resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover}
               />
               <Text key={'name_label_' + e} style={styles.usrEmojiUsernameTxt}>
                  {all_active_users[e].name}
               </Text>
            </View>
         </View>
      )}
```